# Fluent API and One to One

Tags: c#, nhibernate, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, fluent

I am trying to relate an ApplicationRole (IdentityRole) to a Parent role as it's type of Role.  I would like to understand the Fluent API a little better to accomplish this.

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    [StringLength(128)]
    [DisplayName("Based On Role")]
    public string BasedOnRoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BasedOnRoleId")]
    public virtual ApplicationRole BasedOnRole { get; set; }
}
```

I currently have something like this that doesn't work...of course:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>()
                .HasKey(e => e.BasedOnRoleId)
                .HasRequired(e => e.BasedOnRole)
                .WithOptional(e => e.??)
```

Answer (score 0):

See these answers:

[Adding 0..1 relation in EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370899/adding-0-1-relation-in-ef-code-first/43371838#43371838)

[EF 1 to 1..* relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518699/ef-1-to-1-relationship/44519550#44519550)