# Adding 0..1 relation in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following models:

```
public class ItemRental
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ItemRentalId { get; set; }

    public Int32 ItemId { get; set; }
    public Int32 ChargeItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChargeItemId")]
    public Item ChargeItem { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ItemId { get; set; }

    public Int32? ItemRentalId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemRentalId")]
    public ItemRental ItemRental { get; set; }
}
```

`ItemRental` has a 1..N relation with `Item` AND has a 1..N relation with `ChargeItem`.

Problem is that I needed a relation from `Item` back to the `ChargeItem`, so added the property `ItemRentalId` on the `Item`. This is nullable because not every `Item` has to have an `ItemRental`.

Is it possible to create this relation with just annotations?

I tried the fluent api:

```
       modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                    .HasOptional(m => m.ItemRental)
                    .WithRequired(c => c.ChargeItem)
                    .Map(p => p.MapKey("ItemRentalId"));
```

But after doing a migration is it not using the ChargeItemId as a relation.

The problem is when I run this migration it doesn't honor the `ItemRentalId` as a FK navigation property.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, your problem is with mapping the one to zero-or-one relationship.
What you are experiencing is a by-design feature of Entity Framework. Handling one-to-one relationships (and their optional counterparts) is tricky for a lot of reasons. When you do it like this, you cannot specify the foreign key in your model — instead the primary key of your entity will also be the foreign key to the principal end, no extra FK can be specified.

See below for more details on this.

---

**Mapping one-to-zero or one**

So let's say that you have the following model:

```
public class Person
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
  public int CarId { get; set; }
  public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
}

public class MyDemoContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

And now you want to set it up so that you can express the following specification: one person can have one or zero car, and every car belongs to one person exactly (relationships are bidirectional, so if CarA belongs to PersonA, then PersonA 'owns' CarA).

So let's modify the model a bit: add the navigation properties and the foreign key properties:

```
public class Person
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int CarId { get; set; }
  public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
  public int CarId { get; set; }
  public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

And the configuration:

```
public class CarEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
  public CarEntityTypeConfiguration()
  {
     this.HasRequired(c => c.Person).WithOptional(p => p.Car);                        
  }
}
```

By this time this should be self-explanatory. The car has a required person ([*HasRequired()*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671317(v=vs.113).aspx)), with the person having an optional car ([*WithOptional()*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696231(v=vs.113).aspx)). Again, it doesn't matter which side you configure this relationship from, just be careful when you use the right combination of Has/With and Required/Optional. From the `Person` side, it would look like this:

```
public class PersonEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
  public PersonEntityTypeConfiguration()
  {
     this.HasOptional(p => p.Car).WithOptional(c => c.Person);                        
  }
}
```

Now let's check out the db schema:

[image]

Look closely: you can see that there is no FK in `People` to refer to `Car`. Also, the FK in `Car` is not the `PersonId`, but the `CarId`. Here's the actual script for the FK:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cars]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Cars_dbo.People_CarId] FOREIGN KEY([CarId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[People] ([PersonId])
```

So this means that the `CarId` and `PersonId` foregn key properties we have in the model are basically ignored. They are in the database, but they are not foreign keys, as it might be expected. That's because one-to-one mappings does not support adding the FK into your EF model. And that's because one-to-one mappings are quite problematic in a relational database.

The idea is that every person can have exactly one car, and that car can only belong to that person. Or there might be person records, which do not have cars associated with them.

So how could this be represented with foreign keys? Obviously, there could be a `PersonId` in `Car`, and a `CarId` in `People`. To enforce that every person can have only one car, `PersonId` would have to be unique in `Car`. But if `PersonId` is unique in `People`, then how can you add two or more records where `PersonId` is `NULL`(more than one car that don't have owners)? Answer: you can't (well actually, you can create a filtered unique index in SQL Server 2008 and newer, but let's forget about this technicality for a moment; not to mention other RDBMS). Not to mention the case where you specify both ends of the relationship...

The only real way to enforce this rule if the `People` and the `Car` tables have the 'same' primary key (same values in the connected records). And to do this, `CarId` in `Car` must be both a PK and an FK to the PK of People. And this makes the whole schema a mess. When I use this I rather name the PK/FK in `Car` `PersonId`, and configure it accordingly:

```
public class Person
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }        
  public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{        
  public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class CarEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
  public CarEntityTypeConfiguration()
  {
     this.HasRequired(c => c.Person).WithOptional(p => p.Car);
     this.HasKey(c => c.PersonId);
  }
}
```

Not ideal, but maybe a bit better. Still, you have to be alert when using this solution, because it goes against the usual naming conventions, which might lead you astray. Here's the schema generated from this model:

[image]

So this relationship is not enforced by the database schema, but by Entity Framework itself. That's why you have to be very careful when you use this, not to let anybody temper directly with the database.

Comment: So is this a design limitation of EF or Sql server? There must be way that you can define the FK name of a navigation property right?

Comment: I guess it's both. Having a real 1-1 is impossible in a relational database, so you have to do some tricks in EF. Also, a 1-1 association is only feasible if you add a unique constraint to the FK. And I guess that's where EF comes in and solves these problems as it does thus introducing this limitation.

Comment: Yeah I played around with it a bit more, I was able to create the relation in a hacky way in SQL server but can't get it to work in EF. Decided now to change the data model.