# EF 0..1 to 1..* relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there a way to create a zero-or-one to one-or-many relationship in Entity Framework? I've seen plenty examples showing a 0..1 to 0..* relationship, but I want to be sure that in the given example Foo can only exist if it has at least one Bar.

```
class Foo
{
   List<Bar> Bars { get; set; } // Must at least have one Bar
}

class Bar
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; } // Foo is nullable
}
```

I see that this is not easily achieved by SQL since I want a kind of `NOT NULL` at the Foo table instead of at the Bar table, but can Entity Framework handle this?

Comment: Relational databases cannot enforce such relationship using standard constraints. So EF cannot do that as well (not supported).

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but I think you want something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>() 
    .HasMany(t => t.Bars) 
    .WithOptionalPrincipal(t => t.Foo);
```